# In seed laravel does not pull from environment variables correctly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In `.env` following values are set for the user:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:jkUuiJJr7k+TzJwOZUExhJ/Mdr4i3Jg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my-database
DB_USERNAME=my_user
DB_PASSWORD=123
```

On a remote server run seeds, gives the following error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>   Seeded: SiteStringsTableSeeder
>   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>   Seeded: FileGroupsTableSeeder
>   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>   Seeded: AreasTableSeeder
>   PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Faker\Factory' not found in /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 7885

```
class SiteStringsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // mysqldump --max_allowed_packet=1G --no-create-info=TRUE --user=root --default-character-set=utf8 "db_old" "sitestring" > db_old_sitestring.sql
        // mysql -uroot my_user < db_old_sitestring.sql
        $pass_if_pass =  env('DB_PASSWORD');
        $pass_if_pass =  $pass_if_pass ? ' -p'.$pass_if_pass.' ' : ' ';


        exec("mysql -u".env('DB_USERNAME', 'root').$pass_if_pass.
            env('DB_DATABASE', 'db')." < database/seeds/sitestrings_seed.sql");
    }
}
```

Why root, unless specified in .env another user? Thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: try `php artisan config:cache` and than run seeder.

Comment: run this command from root directory of project?

Comment: yes and if it doesn't help than `php artisan config:clear` and than `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: i tried with php artisan config:clear and than php artisan config:cache, same error

Comment: can you wtite `print_r(env('DB_DATABASE'));
        die();` in the start of the run() method and write here what you get?

Comment: i added,  run php artisan db:seed --class=SiteStringsTableSeeder, but dont display in console. where should display?

Comment: It should display in console the output. When I run the same code with my local server it works and outputs my database name

Comment: I added above more one line with print_r('hello'); Yes, this text is display in console, but print_r(env('DB_DATABASE')); nothing

Comment: Hmm. I don't know... your seeder can't see .env file :/

Comment: Have you added an `.env` file on your remote server?

Comment: yes, sure. root@vz45678:/var/www/my_project/.env. I opened now on server

Answer (score 2):

Always reference your **.env variables** only from the config files. To do this go to your config file `app.php` and add your **.env variables** defined in the `.env` file inside the return array like this

```
return [
    'db_username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
    'db_password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
];
```

In your application code use configuration helper `config('app.db_username');` to get the value of the .env variable `DB_USERNAME`.
By doing this the configuration caching will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Config facade:

```
Config::get('filename.attribute');
```

For example:

```
Config::get('app.name);
```